# Avoid flex wrap at first then wrap at smaller screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There is a parent div `.main` contains two child div `.child`. I have set the parent div as `flex-wrap: wrap;`, but the child div is wrapped in the first place when the screen width is wide enough.

```css
.main {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}

.child:first-child {
  flex: 1 0 70%;
}

.child:last-child {
  flex: 1 0 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

They should look like this at first

```css
.main {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}

.child:first-child {
  width: 70%
}

.child:last-child {
  width: 30%
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

And they should wrap when the screen width is so small

```css
.main {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to avoid media query, you may set a flex-grow value and a min-width. min-width set will trigger the wrapping .

example with a min-width set to trigger a break at about 700px:

```css
.main {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}
/* average break point set at 700px 
min-size at break point - 10px(gap + padding/2)   * 0.3 & 0.7 for each div*/

.child:first-child {
  flex: 7 0 auto;
  min-width: calc( 700px - (700px * 0.3) - 10px);
}

.child:last-child {
  flex: 3 0 auto;
  min-width: calc( 700px - (700px * 0.7) - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child">Play me full page then resize the window to check my behavior</div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a media query to tell it when to flex wrap. look what I did here:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.main {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child:first-child {
  flex: 1 0 70%;
}

.child:last-child {
  flex: 1 0 30%;
}
}


.main {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}

.child:first-child {
  width: 70%
}

.child:last-child {
  width: 30%
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a media-query to instruct the browser to use `flex-wrap: wrap;` on `.main` at your desired breaking point.

In this example, I set it to `wrap` at `800px`.

```css
.main {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
}

.child:first-child {
  flex: 1 0 70%;
}

.child:last-child {
  flex: 1 0 30%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .main {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```